# Azure basic vm pricing

Tags: azure

On [this blog post](http://goo.gl/DO6O0M) they announced "basic" pricing for azure vms.  I'm currently using "extra small" for my cloud service web/worker roles in my project.  For these types of vms, would this new basic tier be available?  I'm not seeing it in the VS properties area for these roles, is it just not activated yet or needs a custom change in the config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a few things with this thing:

1. As mentioned in the blog post, this will be available from 3rd of April (i.e. today). I'm guessing you should see it after Scott Guthrie's keynote during BUILD conference today.
2. More importantly, this is only applicable for **`Windows Azure Virtual Machines`** i.e. **`IaaS`** stuff and not for **`Windows Azure Cloud Services`**.